# GM_xmlhttpRequest breaks script

Tags: greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script that will run when the user visits a page, collect some information on the page, then send that info to another location for logging. However whenever the script hits the call to GM_xmlhttpRequest it just halts. For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        GetProfileInfo
// @namespace   LinkedIn
// @include     https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view*
// @version     1
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

console.log("start");
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    onload: function(response) {
        console.log("sent");
    }    
});
console.log("done");
```

Outputs just "start".

I thought I might have to to @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest in the head but when I do that, there is no output at all!

UPDATE:
So it seems I do want to @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest but when I do I get the error "Components.utils.getObjectPrincipal is not a function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest

```
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
```

The result:
start
done
sent